# Can not open JNLP file using Linux?

Tags: java, linux, jnlp, linux-mint

I am trying to load an jnlp file. However I have the following error: `Could not read or parse JNLP file`. I've read that this the problem might be fixed from Mozilla's preferences: Edit -> Preferences -> Applications -> "Java Web Start application". However I dont have "Java Web Start application" section in my Applications (I've installed icedtea-netx but nothing appeares on the Application window). Im using Linux mint. Can someone tell me how to proceed? The solution I refer is in this forum: https://askubuntu.com/questions/91897/first-time-using-java-web-start-in-ubuntu-fatal-launch-exception

EDIT: this is the error that I have:

```
net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Read Error: Could not read or parse the JNLP file. 
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.fromUrl(Launcher.java:491)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:283)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot.run(Boot.java:211)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot.run(Boot.java:53)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot.main(Boot.java:177)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection timed out
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile.openURL(JNLPFile.java:282)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile.<init>(JNLPFile.java:212)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile.<init>(JNLPFile.java:188)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile.<init>(JNLPFile.java:173)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile.<init>(JNLPFile.java:159)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.fromUrl(Launcher.java:477)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: 
java.io.IOException: Connection timed out
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile.openURL(JNLPFile.java:282)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile.<init>(JNLPFile.java:212)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile.<init>(JNLPFile.java:188)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile.<init>(JNLPFile.java:173)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile.<init>(JNLPFile.java:159)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.fromUrl(Launcher.java:477)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:283)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot.run(Boot.java:211)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot.run(Boot.java:53)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot.main(Boot.java:177)
```

Comment: what version openjdk are you using ?

Comment: Also did you install the full icedtea-web ? or just the netx ?

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available [here](https://drive.google.com/?tab=co&authuser=0#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Answer (score 4):

This question is too broad because it doesn't specify what exactly doesn't work.

I'll try to provide a couple of observations

1. You might want to try running the jnlp file "locally" with "javaws" that should reside in the jdk, maybe the jnlp syntax is just wrong.
   More details can be found [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20181005092808/http://vmt.mathforum.org:80/VMTLobby/VMTHelp/howtorunjnlpfiles.html)
2. Alternatively, maybe its some network issue.
3. Next possible reason that jnlp as you wrote it just not supported by the particular version of jdk. I remember in jdk 1.6.10 jnlp just didn't work, so an upgrade to a newer version has effectively solved the problem.

Hope this helps

Comment: It worked for me with javaws 1.5.3 (icedtea-web) . From error output, it indicates you have got a network issue:
`java.io.IOException: Connection timed out`

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have a functioning OpenJDK installed.
And than try to remove and reinstall the icedtea, if you have 6 installed you can upgrade to 7 this way as well.

```
sudo apt-get remove icedtea-6-plugin && sudo apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin
```

Comment: I did but it didnt work. I still dont see any Java Web Start application under the application section